# How to incorporate "Auto Prefixer" into "package.json" and "grunt.js"?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, workflow, autoprefixer

I am a newbie to web-design and as you can imagine, trying to become a full-stack developer with stuff like SaSS, NPM and Grunt is a huge learning curve. I have a boilerplate WordPress theme that incorporates a grunt workflow with sass, a minifier, BrowserSync and all that fun stuff. But it does not have autoprefixer in the workflow and I would like to add it because I would like to start testing out FlexBox designs and that requires a lot of prefixing to make work correctly. I searched the web for how to simply add `Auto Prefixer` to the `gruntfile` and all the answers are super vague with instructions like "just add this code to the `grunt.js` file"... ok well where exactly in the file? This is supposed to be a "post-process" and the `grunt.js` seems to be written in the order it will complete the tasks. I am also not familiar with any of the syntax so just saying "include it" does not help, I am always worried that I didn't put it after a certain bracket or before a semi-colon correctly. I would just like someone to explicitly tell me EXACTLY where I need to put the code in the `grunt.js` file.

As a bonus, I would like to add this to my `package.json` file, so that in the future when I start a new project and I run my initial "install npm" command, it will download `auto prefixer` and be ready to go out the gate.

SO tldr;
How do I download auto prefixer? (is it a set of files in a folder? Where exactly in my project should the folder of files go, just in case I install it in the wrong place initially through the command line)
Where EXACTLY do I need to add the autoprefixer code in my `Grunt.js` file?
Finally, what and where EXACTLY do I need to put into my `package.json` file to make sure that autoprefixer is included in my future projects when I type "install npm" the first time?

I will include both my current `Grunt.js` file and `package.json` file so one of you will be able to simply copy/paste the necessary code in for me. This will help me in the future to know how to add new processes to my workflow.

This is my `Grunt.js` file:

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {
    'use strict';

    // Load all grunt tasks matching the 'grunt-*' pattern
    require( 'load-grunt-tasks' )( grunt );

    // Time how long tasks take.
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Get this party started
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON( 'package.json' ),

        // Global variables
        config: {
            src: 'assets/src',
            dist: 'assets/dist',
            devUrl: 'tayloroyer.local:8888'
        },

        // Libsass
        sass: {
            minified: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    outputStyle: 'compressed', // expanded, nested, compressed
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/main.min.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/main.scss',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.min.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/no-mq.scss'
                }
            },
            expanded: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/main.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/main.scss',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/no-mq.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        // Clean CSS Output
        csscomb: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    config: '<%= config.src %>/sass/csscomb.json'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/main.css': ['<%= config.dist %>/css/main.css'],
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.css': ['<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.css']
                }
            }
        },

        // Concatenate JS Files
        concat: {
            main: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.js': '<%= config.src %>/js/main.js'
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins.js': [
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/boilerplate.js',
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.js',
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/jquery.cycle2.js',
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/jquery.cycle2.swipe.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Minify JS
        uglify: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                preserveComments: 'some'
            },
            main: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.min.js': [ '<%= config.src %>/js/main.js' ]
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins.min.js': [ '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins.js' ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Optimize Media
        imagemin: {
            images: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 3, // default
                    progressive: true // default
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.src %>/img/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/img/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Copy Files/Folders
        copy: {
            js: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/',
                src: 'modernizr-2.8.3.min.js',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins/',
            }
        },

        // Growl Notifications
        notify: {
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    title: 'Browser Updated',
                    message: 'Livereload completed.'
                }
            }
        },

        browserSync: {
            bsFiles: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/img/',
                    '**/*.php'
                ],
            },
            options: {
                // notify: false,
                // open: false,
                watchTask: true,
                proxy: '<%= config.devUrl %>'
            }
        },

        // Run Tasks When Files Are Modified
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '<%= config.src %>/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: [ 'sass:minified' ],
                // tasks: [ 'sass', 'csscomb' ] // slower, but will process all CSS files
            },
            jsMain: {
                files: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/js/main.js'
                ],
                tasks: [ 'uglify:main' ]
            },
            jsPlugins: {
                files: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/**/*.js'
                ],
                tasks: [ 'concat', 'uglify:plugins', 'newer:copy:js' ]
            },
            images: {
                files: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
                ],
                tasks: [ 'newer:imagemin' ]
            },
            // This can be used in place of BrowserSync
            // livereload: {
            //     options: {
            //         livereload: true,
            //         spawn: false
            //     },
            //     files: [
            //         '<%= config.dist %>/css/*.css',
            //         '<%= config.dist %>/js/**/*.js',
            //         '<%= config.dist %>/img/',
            //         // '**/*.php'
            //     ],
            //     tasks: [ 'notify:livereload' ]
            // }
        },

    });

    // Default
    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [
        'sass',
        'csscomb',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'newer:copy:js',
        'newer:imagemin',
        'browserSync',
        'watch', // add after 'browserSync'. Not needed for Livereload
    ]);

    // Build
    // Run all tasks, including sass:expanded
    grunt.registerTask( 'build', [
        'sass',
        'csscomb',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'newer:copy:js',
        'newer:imagemin',
    ]);

    // Images
    grunt.registerTask( 'media', ['newer:imagemin'] );

};
```

This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
"name": "wordpress-theme",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "WordPress theme",
"devDependencies": {
"grunt": "^0.4.5",
"grunt-browser-sync": "^2.1.1",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.1",
"grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.8.0",
"grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.4",
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.9.1",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
"grunt-csscomb": "^3.0.0",
"grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
"grunt-notify": "^0.4.1",
"grunt-sass": "^0.18.1",
"load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0",
"time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "https://github.com/blainerobison/_s.git"
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `npm install grunt-autoprefixer` that will just install [this package](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer) into your project. If you added the flag `--save` that will add this package to `packages.json`. This way, if you are ignoring the `node_modules` directory from version control, you can type `npm install` and it will be fetched automatically.

To clarify, adding the flag means you type the command like this:

```
npm install grunt-autoprefixer --save
```

Now onward to start using it. Usually, in order to use any package in grunt you will find that the documentation tells you to include this on the top of the file

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-package-name'); // e.g grunt-autoprefixer
```

Fortunately, we have a grunt task that automatically check for all grunt tasks on `package.json` file and include them without the need to include the line mentioned above manually. It's this line on your file

```
// Load all grunt tasks matching the 'grunt-*' pattern
require( 'load-grunt-tasks' )( grunt );
```

Now to configure the task, I have modified your Gruntfile.js to this

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {
    'use strict';

    // Load all grunt tasks matching the 'grunt-*' pattern
    require( 'load-grunt-tasks' )( grunt );

    // Time how long tasks take.
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Get this party started
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON( 'package.json' ),

        // Global variables
        config: {
            src: 'assets/src',
            dist: 'assets/dist',
            devUrl: 'tayloroyer.local:8888'
        },

        // Libsass
        sass: {
            minified: {
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    outputStyle: 'compressed', // expanded, nested, compressed
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/main.min.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/main.scss',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.min.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/no-mq.scss'
                }
            },
            expanded: {
                options: {
                    outputStyle: 'expanded'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/main.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/main.scss',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.css': '<%= config.src %>/sass/no-mq.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        // Clean CSS Output
        csscomb: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    config: '<%= config.src %>/sass/csscomb.json'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/main.css': ['<%= config.dist %>/css/main.css'],
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.css': ['<%= config.dist %>/css/no-mq.css']
                }
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>/css/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/css/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Concatenate JS Files
        concat: {
            main: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.js': '<%= config.src %>/js/main.js'
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins.js': [
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/boilerplate.js',
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/jquery.magnific-popup.js',
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/jquery.cycle2.js',
                        '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/jquery.cycle2.swipe.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Minify JS
        uglify: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                preserveComments: 'some'
            },
            main: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/main.min.js': [ '<%= config.src %>/js/main.js' ]
                }
            },
            plugins: {
                files: {
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins.min.js': [ '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins.js' ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Optimize Media
        imagemin: {
            images: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 3, // default
                    progressive: true // default
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.src %>/img/',
                    src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/img/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Copy Files/Folders
        copy: {
            js: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/',
                src: 'modernizr-2.8.3.min.js',
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>/js/plugins/',
            }
        },

        // Growl Notifications
        notify: {
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    title: 'Browser Updated',
                    message: 'Livereload completed.'
                }
            }
        },

        browserSync: {
            bsFiles: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/css/*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/js/**/*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/img/',
                    '**/*.php'
                ],
            },
            options: {
                // notify: false,
                // open: false,
                watchTask: true,
                proxy: '<%= config.devUrl %>'
            }
        },

        // Run Tasks When Files Are Modified
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: '<%= config.src %>/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                tasks: [ 'sass:minified', 'autoprefixer' ], // We added autoprefixer here
                // tasks: [ 'sass', 'csscomb' ] // slower, but will process all CSS files
            },
            jsMain: {
                files: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/js/main.js'
                ],
                tasks: [ 'uglify:main' ]
            },
            jsPlugins: {
                files: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins.js',
                    '<%= config.src %>/js/plugins/**/*.js'
                ],
                tasks: [ 'concat', 'uglify:plugins', 'newer:copy:js' ]
            },
            images: {
                files: [
                    '<%= config.src %>/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'
                ],
                tasks: [ 'newer:imagemin' ]
            },
            // This can be used in place of BrowserSync
            // livereload: {
            //     options: {
            //         livereload: true,
            //         spawn: false
            //     },
            //     files: [
            //         '<%= config.dist %>/css/*.css',
            //         '<%= config.dist %>/js/**/*.js',
            //         '<%= config.dist %>/img/',
            //         // '**/*.php'
            //     ],
            //     tasks: [ 'notify:livereload' ]
            // }
        },

    });

    // Default
    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [
        'sass',
        'autoprefixer', // Adding autoprefixer task
        'csscomb',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'newer:copy:js',
        'newer:imagemin',
        'browserSync',
        'watch', // add after 'browserSync'. Not needed for Livereload
    ]);

    // Build
    // Run all tasks, including sass:expanded
    grunt.registerTask( 'build', [
        'sass',
        'autoprefixer', // Adding autoprefixer task
        'csscomb',
        'concat',
        'uglify',
        'newer:copy:js',
        'newer:imagemin',
    ]);

    // Images
    grunt.registerTask( 'media', ['newer:imagemin'] );

};
```

I would really recommed you read it carefully and refer to the package's documentation. This is not something you do from your memory; people always refer to the documentation when it comes to similar stuff.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot! This is all really confusing to me since Ive been using this process for only 2 weeks now. I would like to clarify a couple things about the process. When you say it will "install the package into my project" you mean that it will download the folders I need to my node modules folder already in my project, correct? And then I have to replace my Grunt.js file with the file you gave me in your answer, correct? and then everything is peachy? When I use the npm install, my Grunt.js file does not change, it just installs the files and adds a line to my package.json, correct?

Comment: First question: Yes correct, the package will be downloaded to node_modules. Replacing grunt file, yes replace your file with mine to get the autoprefixed plugin to work. NPM install doesn't have anything to do  with your Grunt.js file. If you use the --save flag during installation it will modify your package.json that's all

Comment: _**If you used npm install grunt-autoprefixer that will just install this package into your project. If you added the flag --save-dev that will add this package to packages.json.**_ - Thank you!